# Why the node tag of the treeView is null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have this code:

```
public void RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(TreeNode ParentNode, string path)
{
    if (ParentNode.GetNodeCount(true) >= 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode subnode in ParentNode.Nodes)
        {
            string ss = (string)subnode.Tag;
            if (subnode.Tag != null)
            {
                if (ss.Equals("file"))
                {
                    DeleteFile(path + "\\" + subnode.Text, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveDirectoriesRecursive(subnode, path + "\\" + subnode.Text);
            }

        }
    }
    RemoveDirectory(path, true);
}
```

The first time the variable ss is null since subnode is a directory.
But the second time subnode contain a file name: TreeNode: lightning1.jpg

But again ss is null. For some reason subnode.Tag the Tag is null.
Why the Tag is null ? What did i miss here ?

Comment: Did you set the `Tag` property when creating the nodes? Sure you're not looking for `Text`?

Comment: Why would the `Tag` not be `null`? Did you put something in?

Comment: sounds like you need to step thru the code.. have you done that at least ..or did you just code and GO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag property should be assigned before it was using.